# Switch to tab index x in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Could you please tell me which is the shortcut for switching to tab index x in eclipse? Something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for tab 1, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for tab 2 etc...

Comment: To my knowledge, this isn't possible.  Typically I use Cmd (or probably Ctl on Windows) and } or { to move forward or back in history.  This will move you through windows as well.  You can also use Ctrl + E  or Ctrl-Shift-E, to bring up a list of your open editors.   Not sure on windows, but Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab will move you through left and right.

Comment: You can also get a list of all (most) shortcuts by Ctrl-shift-L  (or Cmd-shift-L on Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I think that going directly to a tab with a specific index is not possible at the moment with Eclipse, however ***you have the following options*** :

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>E</kbd>      : pop up a list of the open tabs
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>F6</kbd>     :  will give you a list of open tabs that you can scroll through
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>PAGEUP</kbd> : to navigate to the next right tab
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>PAGEDOWN</kbd> : to navigate to the next left tab